# Convert Cable Modem/Wifi Router to just a Wifi Router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, cable-modem

Looking at buying a cheap Cable Modem/Wifi Gateway combo while I wait for my ISP to get faster speeds, at which point I would buy a pricier DOCSIS 3.1 cable modem.  When that eventually happens, will I be able to convert the old cable modem/wifi combo into just a wifi router (so I don't need to spend extra to get integrated wifi capability on the DOCSIS 3.1 modem)?

I ask because I've seen it mentioned that if your cable modem/wifi router doesn't have a dedicated WAN port (which it doesn't), it can't function as just a wifi router.

Comment: It might possibly work. It should have Ethernet ports. Ignore the WAN side. Hook up an Ethernet port to your network. Set up wireless. You need to be able to turn DHCP OFF on the combo unit, and if you cannot, it will be very limiting.

Comment: Yeah I get the part about DHCP off on the wifirouter and give the wifi router a static address like 192.168.1.2 (assuming modem is 192.168.1.1 and removes the '2' address from its pool). Now that I think about it, it's not really a router anymore, it would just be a wireless switch, which would be fine for my purposes.  It would just need to pass the ARPs so that the client PCs would have the MAC address of the modem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a cable WiFi/router as a router with anything but cable because it doesn't have a WAN port. However, if your cable modem is also a router, then you don't need to use the existing combo as a router, just as a WiFi access point. That will work.

Comment: Yep that's all I need it to to, just be a wireless 'switch'